# Dynamic font sizing/layout in Python/PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have a problem where I need to programmatically lay out text and output a raster image. My initial approach is based around Python and PIL (or Pillow), however I am reasonably language agnostic (as long as it runs on Linux).

I have a list of several thousand long strings, roughly a paragraph each. The naive approach is to use Python's textwrap and PIL's font.getsize() and iterate to find the optimal size, but this seems inefficient to me - there are a lot of strings, and this is potentially running on a Rasperry Pi.

I feel that this is probably a solved problem, but I haven't been able to find a decent solution - I'm not tied to Python/PIL if another stack has a better solution (something in LaTeX? Even matplotlib or something?).

Flexibility to achieve more complex layouts would be a bonus, as well - for example, down the track I would like to treat one part of text as a special case, by increasing the font size and flowing the other text around it.

Any pointers or ideas greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `cairo` (2d graphics) and `pango` ("pretty" text formatting/layout) libraries (they both have binding for python):

- http://cairographics.org/tutorial/
- http://zetcode.com/gui/pygtk/pangoII/
- http://cairographics.org/pycairo_pango/